# Creating an array from text between parentheses by comma delimited value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the value of an existing array that looks like this:

```
Product One (Amount: 199.99 USD, Select Option: Option One, Product One (CRM): 1)
```

What I am trying to get out of this is an array that looks like this:

```
Product One 
    Amount: 199.99 USD
    Select Option: Option One
    Product One (CRM): 1
```

What I've tried is:

```
$product_arr = json_decode($product_details[0]);
$prod_arr_add = preg_split('/[\,(]+/', $product_arr[0]);
print_r ($prod_arr_add);
```

Which looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Product One 
    [1] => Amount: 199.99 USD
    [2] =>  Select Option: Option One
    [3] =>  Product One 
    [4] => CRM): 1)
)
```

And other attempts with variances of what I've tried have failed to produce desired results similarly.

**How can I split the string of text into an array?**

Comment: **User deleted comment above. Suggested I use explode() -

Ok, tried that. This is what I get:

`Array
(
    [0] => Product One (Amount: 199.99 USD
    [1] => Select Option: Option One
    [2] => Product One (CRM): 1)
)`

How can I remove the two rogue parentheses?

Comment: If the pattern holds across all products, you can try to use a regular expression like [this one](https://regex101.com/r/aRmO1k/1).

Answer (score 0):

With only one sample string to test against, I have so make some assumptions and sacrifice regex pattern efficiency.  If this solution needs to be tightened up, please comment and/or edit your question.

```
$regex="/^(.+?)\s\((.*?),\s(.*?),\s(.*)\)$/";
$string="Product One (Amount: 199.99 USD, Select Option: Option One, Product One (CRM): 1)";

if(preg_match($regex,$string,$matches)){
    $prod_arr_add=array_slice($matches,1);  // remove first element from the array (fullmatch)
    echo "<pre>";
        var_export($prod_arr_add);
    echo "</pre>";
}else{
    echo "no match";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Product One',
  1 => 'Amount: 199.99 USD',
  2 => 'Select Option: Option One',
  3 => 'Product One (CRM): 1'
)
```

Regex:

```
^(.+?)\s\(  #Capture everything from the start to a space followed by a opening parenthesis
(.*?),\s    #Capture everything before a comma followed by a space 
(.*?),\s    #Capture everything before a comma followed by a space
(.*)\)$     #Capture everything before a closing parenthesis at the end of the string
```

Comment: @jarmerson answer edited.  If this satisfied your question please award me the green tick, if not let me know what else is the trouble.

Comment: Awesome. I am currently working on a separate project but this is scheduled to be continued this coming week and I will absolutely try it on and get back to you.